# Should I be using y_pred or y_pred_proba for binary Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, auc, roc

I have a binary classification problem and i want to plot ROC/AUC curve, should I use ypred or ypred_proba

Answer (score 1):

`y_pred_proba` gives the predicted probability.

`y_pred` takes the probability and then rounds to category $0$ or category $1$.

You need some kind of continuum of values in order to vary the classification threshold and draw a ROC curve, so use `y_pred_proba`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what Client want as an outcome. Two cases to be mentioned here.

###### Case-1: If client wants just the **Predicted Class** go with **y_pred**, as it outputs the class.

###### Case-2: If client wants the **probability of that record belongs to a specific class** go with **y_pred_proba**

***Note: Most of the times the actual probability and predicted probability might have a huge difference, so need to calibrate the model(Platt, Isotonic)***

Comment: On top of @karteek's answer, please find here [sklearn's material on calibration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) in case you are interested.